# Finding the most recent value being logged in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having a table containing 3 columns -`time_stamp,meter_id,value` . All the meter_ids are logging value in areal time .EX-:

```
    time_stamp      value   meter_id

06/14/13 12:17:00   1212    1
06/15/13 12:20:01   12      1
06/16/13 12:25:30   1213    2
06/17/13 12:30:12   12333   2
06/18/13 12:32:34   111111  3
```

I need to find the most recent value for each meter_id.

**Edit**

Final output should be -:

```
time_stamp          value   meter_id

06/15/13 12:20:01   12        1
06/17/13 12:30:12   12333     2
06/18/13 12:32:34   111111    3
```

I hope this will help you to understand my question.

thanks

Comment: time_stamp is logging time?

Answer (score 1):

May be you want something like this?

```
select value, Meter_id from table group by Meter_id order by time_stamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I  am guessing time_stamp is logging time, if so try this

```
SELECT MAX(time_stamp),meter_id,value FROM table GROUP BY meter_id
```

Comment: your query will give the max value if the value is increasing every time ..but Some times its the case like some meter_ids are switched off or the value is less than previous value

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you want most recent entry for all the meter ids.
You can self join the table and use `group by`

```
select
b.time_stamp, b.value, b.meter_id
from
  your_table as b
  inner join (
    select max(time_stamp) as recent_time, meter_id
    from your_table
    group by meter_id
  ) as view on ( view.meter_id = b.meter_id  and view.unique_key_from_your_table = b.unique_key_from_your_table)
```

If you don't have any unique key but timestamp. You can take `time_stamp` as `unique_key_from_your_table`

So join condition will look like

```
view.meter_id = b.meter_id and view.recent_time = b.time_stamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select r.*
from myTable r
join (select meter_id, max(time_stamp) max_time
      from myTable
      group by meter_id) m
  on r.meter_id = m.meter_id and r.time_stamp = m.max_time
```